# Mod_Rewrite A Single Dynamic PHP Page To A Different Site Entirely?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my problem:

Old Site used dynamic urls, so everything looked like -

**oldsite.com/section.php?id=[number]**

New Site has flattened those URLs to .html, so there's no need to rewrite those.

However! Old Site gave section.php?id=[number] to links on a linkroll, so something like -

**oldsite.com/section.php?id=653** might have previously redirected to, say, **stackoverflow.com**.

My question: is it possible to set this up via mod_redirect so I can permanently point these random dynamic URLs to their real-life counterparts that are not actually on my server?

Because each one is unique, they'll need to all be separate entries (I think?).

Any help you can offer is much appreciated!

Comment: [`.htaccess` tutorial](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=.+$
RewriteRule ^section.php$ http://example.com/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi Starkeen, thanks for this. Just so I'm 100% clear, where would I customize this to include each page number?

Comment: Tabby the rule handles dynamic query strings. This will redirect all urls of the following format **/section.php?id=anynumber**

Comment: I got it! For others' future reference, I just changed:

^id=.+$

to 

^id=[number]$

Thank you!